# Return Output of some function or event to some new page or template in Meteor with Iron:router

Tags: templates, meteor, iron-router

I am working on some project, i want to return filtered data to some new page, what i am facing right now is, that output is shown on same template, so lot of extra stuff occurs which i do not want. I want to redirect it using router, but this filter function is a part of images_thumbnail.

```
Client > main.html
```

```html
    <template name="images_thumbnail">
        //lot of stuff  + images

       {{#each images}}  //show all images from public folder
           <img src=""some_image.jpg" alt="img_title" />
           <caption>
               <a href="#" class="js-set-genre-filter"> 
                  {{img_genre}}  //image_genre associated with this image
               </a>
            </caption>
       {{/each}}  
    </template>
```

When I click image genre (say Thriller, Comedy, etc.), image filter is set

```
Client > main.js
```

```js
    Router.route('/images', function(){
       this.render('navigation_bar',{
          to: 'header'
       });
       this.render('owl_carousel', {
          to: 'carousel'
       });

       //images_thumbnail template along with navbar, carousel
       this.render('images_thumbnail', {
          to: 'body'
       });
    });

    Tempalte.images_thumbanil.events({
       'click .js-set-genre-filter':function(event){
            Session.set("genreFilter", this.img_genre);
            console.log(this.img_genre);   //gives Comedy/Thriller
        }
    })

    Template.images_thumbnail.helpers({
       images:function(){
          if(Session.get("genreFilter"))
             return Images.find({img_genre: Session.get("genreFilter")};  
         
         //This is the output, but i want to redirect it to some 
         //new template, instead of images_thumbnail template
       }
    })
```

When no filter is set
[Output when no Filter is set, Navigation bar, Carousel, rest stuff is visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMpgs.jpg)

Filter output, when genreFilter is set
[Navigation bar, button, Headings are shown which are not needed for this content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5333v.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I understand fully what you want,
if you want to redirect your route to another at the point of your code,
simply [use Router.go('/newPath')](https://gist.github.com/LeCoupa/59738c28fdc9085b9212#file-iron-router-cheatsheet-coffee-L182)

In addition,
Iron router was great package still,
but Meteor Developer Group(MDG) and a lot of people changed to use [FlowRouter](https://gist.github.com/LeCoupa/59738c28fdc9085b9212#file-iron-router-cheatsheet-coffee-L182)
because of maintanence and to focus on routing itself. (Iron Router controls pub/sub and lifecycle too much.)

So consider to FlowRouter too-